Jest transform in package.json isn't being called
I'm using Create React App and I'd like to add a transform function to Jest. I'm doing this in the package.json using:
{
  ...
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "**/*.test.{ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "globalSetup": "./global-setup.js",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.ts$": "<rootDir>/transformer.js"
    }
  },
  ...

The transformer.js file is simply:
module.exports = {
  process(src, filename, config, options) {
    console.log(src);
    return src;
  },
};

While this example is very simple I've tried more complex changes to update the file but nothing works. Removing the process method will cause the test not to run at all so the transformer is being used by jest, its just not being applied to the files.
Is there something I'm missing.

"I'm using Create React App" Why? it's not recommended to be used anymore.
